# Ignore / from @requestmapping value in MVC Spring

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, url-routing

My `file path` or directory like `a/b/c/d`
I am triggered this in rest but i am `getting HTTP Status 404 error`.

i want to ignore / from filepath and want to `print like a/b/c/d` without 404 error.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/TEST/{filepath:./*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void DownloadFile(@PathVariable("filepath") String filePath) {


    System.out.println(filePath);

}
```

This is what i am triggered in rest `TEST/a/b/c/d` 
Please Help..

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not use PathVariable:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/TEST/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void DownloadFile(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String filePath = (String) request.getAttribute(
            HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);

    System.out.println(filePath.substring(filePath.indexOf("TEST")));

}
```